# Modal popup in Angular JS without Bootstrap CSS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a plugin for a modal directive in Angular but there is a requirement not to use the Bootstrap CSS.  Angular-UI looks nice but obviously depends on Bootstrap.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Angular-UI you can define your own templates and in case of CSS you can **for sure** use your own files.

[Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/modal/) are standard templates for `modal`. The only dependencies on Bootstrap I found are: `modal` and `modal-backdrop` so just rename them for your needs or add them to your CSS to get custom styling.

Btw: Angular-UI is modular so you can just use these directives which you really need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know existing plugin to achieve this without Bootstrap (I use Angular-UI), but you can easily create your own directive using jQuery UI modal.

There are lots of tuto on the internet to create directive for jQuery UI.

I have found a JSFiddle in this [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/45k7hTTX0qY/IMOsu_ptSWsJ) (you have to follow the link in the answer of January 4). User has made a simple directive based on jQuery.

I think it will put you on the right way.